# How to prefix two decimal number in textfield

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I'm new with flutter and wondering is it possible to prefix the number with decimal in textfield. The prefix number is 0.00 and should not delete it.

```html
<blockquote class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="VnFQQlo"><a href="https://imgur.com/VnFQQlo">View post on imgur.com</a></blockquote><script async src="//s.imgur.com/min/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

So far i have tried something like limited two decimal entry.

```
 CupertinoFormRow(
                  child: CupertinoTextFormFieldRow(
                    controller: controller.price,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      controller.calTotal(controller.qty.text, value);
                    },
                    placeholder: "Enter item price",
                    inputFormatters: [
                      FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                          RegExp(r'^\d+\.?\d{0,2}')),
                    ],
                  ),
                  prefix: Text('0.00'),
                ),
```

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your code. Please share a dummy code for the `controller` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use [currency_text_input_formatter](https://pub.dev/packages/currency_text_input_formatter)

```
CupertinoFormRow(
      child: CupertinoTextFormFieldRow(
      controller: controller.price,
      onChanged: (value) {
         controller.calTotal(controller.qty.text, value);
           },
      placeholder: "Enter item price",
      inputFormatters: [
           CurrencyTextInputFormatter(decimalDigits: 2),
                  ],
              ),
       ),
```